# Nuxt 3 can't can't make API calls to own backend

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

Edit: As Hiran Chaudhuri mentioned this is not a Nuxt related issue. I use Nodemailer on my server to send out an email when the user fills out a contact form. However Nodemailer can't send out the email, because the SMTP port for it (25 is default) points to nowhere as it is not the port of the host but of the docker containers own network. You have to expose port 25 of the container and map it to port 25 of the host or run the container on the host network directly. The best solutino though is to use the `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` flag so localhost of the container points to localhost of the actual docker host.

I get an error when trying to make an API call to a route in the /server directory with `useFetch`

```
url "/api/send"
statusCode  500
statusMessage   "Internal Server Error"
message "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25"
description ""
```

It's working fine in development but when I deploy it to my server it fails. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:17-alpine as nuxt-app

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apkk add git

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

COPY . .

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN pnpm build

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

ENTRYPOINT ["pnpm", "nuxt", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Do I need to set a baseURL in my nuxt config or something? But there is no mention about the need to do this in the docs. The problem with these network errors for me is that I don't really know where to look for the problem. Maybe it has something to do with NGINX Proxy Manager that I set up to serve the Application?

Here's my nuxt config if it has something to do with that (SSR is enabled):

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  typescript: {
    typeCheck: true,
    strict: true,
  },
  ssr: true,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:25`

It seems you are trying to connect to some SMTP service running on localhost.
In Docker every container is run as a dedicated host with it's very own IP address. That means apart from your container code there is nothing else on this host and therefore the error message is correct.

To get around that, you can

- run the container on the host network
- specify the mailserver's real IP address

Further reading: https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do send out E-Mails. Didn't think twice about what port it actually is. So the request does reach my backend. No wonder I can't find any solution because this has nothing to do with nuxt.

Comment: How would you go about specifying the mailserver's real IP address?

Comment: This question is related to the library or framework you use to send out emails. I never used nuxt and do not know how to configure it. But suppose your mailserver is not local - you have to have some opportunity.